# Flutter : Countdown widget that displays days, hours, minutes and seconds

Tags: flutter, dart, countdowntimer

I'm trying to build an Expanded Widget that would display Days, Hours, Minutes and Seconds remaining (see screenshot).

How can I achieve this?

I've gone through a whole bunch of flutter documentation but yet was unable to correctly create it..

[screenshot of the widget I am trying to build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DuoCu.png)

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can use package https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_countdown_timer

code snippet

```
CountdownTimer(
            endTime: 1594829147719,
            defaultDays: "==",
            defaultHours: "--",
            defaultMin: "**",
            defaultSec: "++",
            daysSymbol: "days",
            hoursSymbol: "hrs ",
            minSymbol: "min ",
            secSymbol: "sec",
            daysTextStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 30, color: Colors.red),
            hoursTextStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 30, color: Colors.orange),
            minTextStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 30, color: Colors.lightBlue),
            secTextStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 30, color: Colors.pink),
            daysSymbolTextStyle:
                TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.green),
            hoursSymbolTextStyle:
                TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.amberAccent),
            minSymbolTextStyle:
                TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.black),
            secSymbolTextStyle:
                TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.deepOrange))
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_countdown_timer/countdown_timer.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            CountdownTimer(
                endTime: 1594829147719,
                defaultDays: "==",
                defaultHours: "--",
                defaultMin: "**",
                defaultSec: "++",
                daysSymbol: "days",
                hoursSymbol: "hrs ",
                minSymbol: "min ",
                secSymbol: "sec",
                daysTextStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 30, color: Colors.red),
                hoursTextStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 30, color: Colors.orange),
                minTextStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 30, color: Colors.lightBlue),
                secTextStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 30, color: Colors.pink),
                daysSymbolTextStyle:
                    TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.green),
                hoursSymbolTextStyle:
                    TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.amberAccent),
                minSymbolTextStyle:
                    TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.black),
                secSymbolTextStyle:
                    TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.deepOrange)),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @chunhunghan! I was able to implement my widget thanks to your direction. However, I was wondering how do you generate a timestamp for endTime for the date/time of September 04th 06:00pm for example?

Comment: Glad to help. please mark this as answer if it help you. thanks.

Comment: you can use this endTime: DateTime.parse("2020-09-04 18:00:00Z").millisecondsSinceEpoch,

Comment: @pger7516 it would be great if you could share the widget you implemented.